# Can I create a camera app with video and photo functions on web instead of native?

Tags: web-apps

I am curious why not many people building web applications so we can do away with native downloads. What are the limitations?

Not a programmer, looking for advice.

Answer (score 0):

Because Native apps are faster, and provides access to various device features(Sensors,Camera,..etc). Plus they are more responsive and works very smooth as compare to web app.
However, React JS can be used to develop Native apps.

Yes, you can create Camera app on web, HTML 5 technology provides everything you need.